# Retrieve clients geolocation info from AWS ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We want to be able to identify what country our users are coming from when visiting our site. I know ELB supports the Proxy protocol and will send through the client's IP; which I could use to do a IP geo-lookup manually. But does ELB have anything built into it that would tell me how to get the user's location info, perhaps through a header? Don't need much info, just the client's country.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ELB does not offer this capability.  Cloudfront, however, does.
[Amazon CloudFront Adds Device Detection, Geo Targeting, Host Header Forwarding, CORS Support, and more!](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/06/26/amazon-cloudfront-device-detection-geo-targeting-host-header-cors/)

You could use CloudFront in front of your ELB (configuring the ELB as a "custom origin") and then enable the `Cloudfront-Viewer-Country` header, which does two things: allows you to know the geolocation lookup result, and causes Cloudfront to keep a country-specific cache of every cacheable resource (so cached responses still behave on a country-specific basis.)

You can also enable headers that will identify the browser as desktop, mobile, tablet, or smart television.

Look closely at the fine print of the pricing structure and you will find that in some cases (depending on the country, configuration, and traffic volume) using CloudFront in front of EC2 can actually be almost $0.005/GB less expensive than not using it, as strange as that seems, due to recent price structure changes.

Comment: Does CloudFront offer a way to enrich the (cached) **response** headers with geolocation data?

Comment: @Gabriel CloudFront provides this info to the origin server in request headers.  The origin could add them, or information derived from them, to the response, but CloudFront doesn't add them to the response.

Comment: Thanks. But then, CloudFront would cache the response returned by origin. This is not what I am seeking. I need an appropriate Geo response (through custom response headers for example) to every request. The body, though, shall be cached of course.

Comment: @Gabriel, you say *"But then, CloudFront would cache the response returned by origin"* but no, it won't -- not in the way you are thinking it will.  With this feature enabled, CloudFront will cache more than one copy of the same page, and will do the right thing, based on the available cached responses and the parameters of the current request.  The CloudFront caching logic is very "correct" in this sense.